# Laravel 5.2 live chat with socket.io and redis private message

Tags: php, node.js, sockets, laravel

TLDR; best solution for private instant messenger with laravel.

So I have a live real time chat working on my laravel site, However at the moment I don't have the ability to private message, its located on the home page and every time someone connects their socket.id changes The code I used and modified was from this tutorial. (I can copy paste it here if you wish I was not to sure about the rules regarding that)

http://itsolutionstuff.com/post/laravel-52-chat-message-module-using-socketio-redis-express-and-nodejs-from-from-scratchexample.html

I have no idea where to go about settings this up between 2 users as a private chat and just wondering if anyone else has ended up getting an instant messenger type system working with laravel and if so any info would be appreciated - it does not have to be socket but I was wondering is ajax a bad way of going about it.

Comment: Did you eventually get this set up? Would be interested in your solution.

Comment: @121c updated :)

Answer (score 2):

I ended up creating each user who signs in a room of their own using a random token.
When someone requests to pm them it is announced and they have the open to start a chat (*a new lobby*).
It then combines both tokens using their user ids in which order to combine them as the lobby.
I have also save each thread in the db using this method.
When a token expires it updates the token in the DB also.

I am sure this is not secure, however it is not enterprise or even used publicy more so a test.
If anyone else has a more secure or better way let us know.

Comment: Thanks Michael I appreciate your answer.